# CSS Rotate and Replace Image at the Same Time

Tags: css, image, rotation, swap

Can someone help me understand how, using CSS, I can rotate and change an image at the same time on hover?  When a user hovers over an image I want to start the rotation and change the image during the middle of the rotation.  So far I have the following but I can not figure out how to delay the image change on hover.

```
.image-swap {
    background: url("image1.jpg") no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
.image-swap:hover {
    background: url("image2.jpg") no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need to add `background-image` to the `transition` rule.

In this example, I also use a container element to trigger the hover (otherwise the interactive area rotates with the image, which causes jerkiness if the cursor gets caught on, say, a moving corner).

```css
.image-swap-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-swap {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/300x300/ff0000");
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    transform: none;
    transition: transform 1s, background-image 1s;
}

.image-swap-container:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.image-swap-container:hover .image-swap {
    background: url("http://placehold.it/300x300/00ff00");
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-swap-container"><div class="image-swap"></div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out.  That was exactly what I needed.